# Delay a job in azure pipeline YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How to delay a job in azure devops pipelines, I have multiple that will be running simultaneously, the problem is in the checkout phase I get the error saying files are used by another process.

I found "delayForMinutes" and running a powershell script but they only work for tasks not for jobs.

My goal is to have the checkout phase for the job to be delayed not the tasks in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like after the checkout job add a [agentless Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks) with in that you can include a [delay task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delay?view=azure-devops). Then you can continue the other task in a separate agent job

[image]